# how to resolve Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to connect20.magentocommerce.com:443

Tags: php, magento, ssl

whenever wants to integrate module through magento connect always get the error
"Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to connect20.magentocommerce.com:443".

Still i am integrate the module by using:
http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Any solution help me out
Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled `php_openssl` in your `php.ini`

Comment: yes i have enabled php_openssl in php.ini

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Please try this,Hope It's helpful for you.**

> downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_HTTP
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Class to work with HTTP protocol using curl library
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Connect
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_HTTP_Client_Curl
implements Mage_HTTP_IClient
{
    /**
     * Session Cookie storage, magento_root/var directory used
     * @var string
     */
    const COOKIE_FILE = 'var/cookie';

    /**
     * Hostname
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_host = 'localhost';

    /**
     * Port
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_port = 80;

    /**
     * Stream resource
     * @var object
     */
    protected $_sock = null;

    /**
     * Request headers
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_headers = array();


    /**
     * Fields for POST method - hash
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_postFields = array();

    /**
     * Request cookies
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_cookies = array();

    /**
     * Response headers
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_responseHeaders = array();

    /**
     * Response body
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_responseBody = '';

    /**
     * Response status
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_responseStatus = 0;


    /**
     * Request timeout
     * @var intunknown_type
     */
    protected $_timeout = 300;

    /**
     * TODO
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_redirectCount = 0;

    /**
     * Curl
     * @var object
     */
    protected $_ch;


    /**
     * User ovverides options hash
     * Are applied before curl_exec
     *
     * @var array();
     */
    protected $_curlUserOptions = array();

    /**
     * User credentials
     *
     * @var array();
     */
    protected $_auth = array();

    /**
     * Set request timeout, msec
     *
     * @param int $value
     */
    public function setTimeout($value)
    {
        $this->_timeout = (int) $value;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Destructor
     * Removes temporary environment
     */
    public function __destruct()
    {
        if (is_file(self::COOKIE_FILE)) {
            @unlink(self::COOKIE_FILE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set headers from hash

     * @param array $headers
     */
    public function setHeaders($headers)
    {
        $this->_headers = $headers;

    }

    /**
     * Add header
     *
     * @param $name name, ex. "Location"
     * @param $value value ex. "http://google.com"
     */
    public function addHeader($name, $value)
    {
        $this->_headers[$name] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Remove specified header
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function removeHeader($name)
    {
        unset($this->_headers[$name]);

    }

    /**
     * Authorization: Basic header
     * Login credentials support
     *
     * @param string $login username
     * @param string $pass password
     */
    public function setCredentials($login, $pass)
    {
        $this->_auth['login'] = $login;
        $this->_auth['password'] = $pass;
        //$val= base64_encode( "$login:$pass" );
        //$this->addHeader( "Authorization", "Basic $val" );
    }

    /**
     * Add cookie
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $value
     */
    public function addCookie($name, $value)
    {
        $this->_cookies[$name] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Remove cookie
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function removeCookie($name)
    {
        unset($this->_cookies[$name]);
    }

    /**
     * Set cookies array
     *
     * @param array $cookies
     */
    public function setCookies($cookies)
    {
        $this->_cookies = $cookies;
    }

    /**
     * Clear cookies
     */
    public function removeCookies()
    {
        $this->setCookies(array());
    }


    /**
     * Make GET request
     *
     * @param string $uri uri relative to host, ex. "/index.php"
     */
    public function get($uri)
    {
        $this->makeRequest("GET", $uri);
    }

    /**
     * Make POST request
     * @see lib/Mage/HTTP/Mage_HTTP_Client#post($uri, $params)
     */
    public function post($uri, $params)
    {
        $this->makeRequest("POST", $uri, $params);
    }


    /**
     * Get response headers
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getHeaders()
    {
        return $this->_responseHeaders;
    }


    /**
     * Get response body
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->_responseBody;
    }

    /**
     * Get cookies response hash
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCookies()
    {
        if(empty($this->_responseHeaders['Set-Cookie'])) {
            return array();
        }
        $out = array();
        foreach( $this->_responseHeaders['Set-Cookie'] as $row) {
            $values = explode("; ", $row);
            $c = count($values);
            if(!$c) {
                continue;
            }
            list($key, $val) = explode("=", $values[0]);
            if(is_null($val)) {
                continue;
            }
            $out[trim($key)] = trim($val);
        }
        return $out;
    }


    /**
     * Get cookies array with details
     * (domain, expire time etc)
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCookiesFull()
    {
        if(empty($this->_responseHeaders['Set-Cookie'])) {
            return array();
        }
        $out = array();
        foreach( $this->_responseHeaders['Set-Cookie'] as $row) {
            $values = explode("; ", $row);
            $c = count($values);
            if(!$c) {
                continue;
            }
            list($key, $val) = explode("=", $values[0]);
            if(is_null($val)) {
                continue;
            }
            $out[trim($key)] = array('value'=>trim($val));
            array_shift($values);
            $c--;
            if(!$c) {
                continue;
            }
            for($i = 0; $i<$c; $i++) {
                list($subkey, $val) = explode("=", $values[$i]);
                $out[trim($key)][trim($subkey)] = trim($val);
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }

    /**
     * Get response status code
     * @see lib/Mage/HTTP/Mage_HTTP_Client#getStatus()
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->_responseStatus;
    }

    /**
     * Make request
     * @param string $method
     * @param string $uri
     * @param array $params
     * @return null
     */
    protected function makeRequest($method, $uri, $params = array())
    {
        static $isAuthorizationRequired = 0;
        $this->_ch = curl_init();

        // make request via secured layer
        if ($isAuthorizationRequired && strpos($uri, 'https://') !== 0) {
            $uri = str_replace('http://', '', $uri);
            $uri = 'https://' . $uri;
        }

        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

        // force method to POST if secured
        if ($isAuthorizationRequired) {
            $method = 'POST';
        }

        if($method == 'POST') {
            $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            $postFields = is_array($params) ? $params : array();
            if ($isAuthorizationRequired) {
                $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, self::COOKIE_FILE);
                $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, self::COOKIE_FILE);
                $postFields = array_merge($postFields, $this->_auth);
            }
            if (!empty($postFields)) {
                $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
            }
        } elseif($method == "GET") {
            $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
        } else {
            $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        }

        if(count($this->_headers)) {
            $heads = array();
            foreach($this->_headers as $k=>$v) {
                $heads[] = $k.': '.$v;
            }
            $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $heads);
        }

        if(count($this->_cookies)) {
            $cookies = array();
            foreach($this->_cookies as $k=>$v) {
                $cookies[] = "$k=$v";
            }
            $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_COOKIE, implode(";", $cookies));
        }

        if($this->_timeout) {
            $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->_timeout);
        }

        if($this->_port != 80) {
            $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_PORT, $this->_port);
        }

        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this,'parseHeaders'));

        if(count($this->_curlUserOptions)) {
            foreach($this->_curlUserOptions as $k=>$v) {
                $this->curlOption($k, $v);
            }
        }

        $this->_responseHeaders = array();
        $this->_responseBody = curl_exec($this->_ch);
        $err = curl_errno($this->_ch);
        if($err) {
            $this->doError(curl_error($this->_ch));
        }
        if(!$this->getStatus()) {
            return $this->doError("Invalid response headers returned from server.");
        }
        curl_close($this->_ch);
        if (403 == $this->getStatus()) {
            if (!$isAuthorizationRequired) {
                $isAuthorizationRequired++;
                $this->makeRequest($method, $uri, $params);
                $isAuthorizationRequired=0;
            } else {
                return $this->doError(sprintf('Access denied for %s@%s', $_SESSION['auth']['login'], $uri));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Throw error excpetion
     * @param $string
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function isAuthorizationRequired()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['auth']['username']) && isset($_SESSION['auth']['password']) && !empty($_SESSION['auth']['username'])) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Throw error excpetion
     * @param $string
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function doError($string)
    {
        throw new Exception($string);
    }


    /**
     * Parse headers - CURL callback functin
     *
     * @param resource $ch curl handle, not needed
     * @param string $data
     * @return int
     */
    protected function parseHeaders($ch, $data)
    {
        if(preg_match('/^HTTP\/[\d\.x]+ (\d+)/', $data, $m)) {
            if (isset($m[1])) {
                $this->_responseStatus = (int)$m[1];
            }
        } else {
            $name = $value = '';
            $out = explode(": ", trim($data), 2);
            if(count($out) == 2) {
                $name = $out[0];
                $value = $out[1];
            }

            if(strlen($name)) {
                if("Set-Cookie" == $name) {
                    if(!isset($this->_responseHeaders[$name])) {
                        $this->_responseHeaders[$name] = array();
                    }
                    $this->_responseHeaders[$name][] = $value;
                } else {
                    $this->_responseHeaders[$name] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        return strlen($data);
    }

    /**
     * Set curl option directly
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $value
     */
    protected function curlOption($name, $value)
    {
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, $name, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Set curl options array directly
     * @param array $array
     */
    protected function curlOptions($array)
    {
        curl_setopt_array($this->_ch, $arr);
    }

    /**
     * Set CURL options ovverides array  *
     */
    public function setOptions($arr)
    {
        $this->_curlUserOptions = $arr;
    }

    /**
     * Set curl option
     */
    public function setOption($name, $value)
    {
        $this->_curlUserOptions[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

> After change please refresh the shop cache.

Comment: Hello code works fine yesterday, but today when I refresh the page then error comes same , so can you please tell me what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Cause
downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php now requires newer SSL protocol support with functions added in PHP5.5 (TLSv1.1 or newer) can not connect to repo server with cURL libs available for PHP on your host.
Solution
Ask your hosting provider to bring TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 support in cURL libs of PHP and upgrade PHP to newer version. In the meantime, you can proceed with the extension installation or upgrades by lowering SSL requirements in downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php: